# Process memory usage high in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks, heap-memory

When looking at the memory usage for a single page app (Angular 7 and .net core 2), IE tends to start off at a higher memory limit to begin with compared to Chrome.

IE-11 started off at 165 MB and after navigating between several pages for a minute, it has ended at 354 MB and then you can see the flat line at the end because of inactivity.

[image: IE-11 memory usage]

Same test in Chrome, it started at 36 MB and ended at 105 MB.

[image]

Question is, why IE starts off with higher memory limit like 165 MB and is there anything we can do to lower it down to match or at least come close to what Chrome is using (36 MB)? Happy to add any other details into the question. Thanks!

Comment: Try to refer this link may give some hint about memory leak in IE browser. Ref: https://medium.com/@garthw/how-to-work-around-ie-memory-leaks-in-spas-b2f6bc7c9ae9

Comment: ok, I'll check that. The other thing I noticed is, even if you open a blank tab and start recording memory usage, IE starts off at ~40MB which is weird and Chrome at ~2MB. And, then open google (for example) and you will see IE jumping to ~76MB and Chrome to ~10MB. I don't know how to explain the initial 40MB usage in IE-11.

Comment: If we talk about a blank tab than It is not fair to compare IE with Chrome because both are product of different company. I had seen some cases where IE starts consuming more memory after Windows updates. I suggest you to reset your IE and than again try to install latest updates for your Windows OS. If it is related with any specific update than it can be solved by installing the latest updates.